# How Do I Add History To My Migrated Git Repo?

Tags: git, svn

I had an SVN project with several years of commit history in it.

However, it was migrated to git a couple of years ago by putting trunk into master as a single commit thus destroying all the history.

Since then there have been lots of commits added to the git repo.

Obviously every time you do `git blame` now you stop at the "Initial commit" so it doesn't give you all the svn history, which is often the part I am interested in.

I have subsequently found another git repo with a much more normal svn to git migration from the original svn repo.
However, this one stops at the head of svn trunk.

Is it possible to join these 2 repos together in order to restore the svn history in the git repo?

I am concerned that trying to do `git rebase` is going to cause large amounts of conflicts due to the inital commit of trunk to master.

Is there a better way to splice them together?

I don't want a solution like `git subtree` where the history stops with a hash reference and you then have to do another git log on that hash.
I need to be able to do `git blame` or `git log` and get all of the git history **and** svn history together.

Assume that it is OK that the recent commit hashes are going to change.

Comment: You *can* graft the two histories together. Whether this really goes smoothly ... depends on things that are impossible to guess. Look at using `git replace` to make a replacement for the root commit of the new-history repository that goes to the equivalent commit in the properly-converted SVN repository. If you can get that to work nicely, you can then "cement the graft into place" using a no-op `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`.

Comment: Having turned the graft into a true new history, the new repository is now ready to be used instead of the old one. Note: there's a newer, faster command, `git filter-repo`, that's a big improvement over the old `git filter-branch`, but filter-repo isn't included with Git yet, so you have to go get it separately from wherever it is kept.